# Is there a way to get the iOS phone contacts from safari browser with React/Angular js?

Tags: reactjs, angular

I'm trying to find a solution to this. I only found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Contact_Picker_API but seems that is not working correctly for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get contact picker api working for IOS if you go to your settings and turn on the contact picker api feature flag in your safari settings.

Go to:

```
Settings>Safari>Advanced>Feature Flags
```

In the feature flags, you’ll find contact picker API, and can switch it on to use it on IOS. The advanced folder is at the bottom of the page and the feature flags is also at the bottom.

As of Nov 2023, there is no plan to support contact picker api natively in safari